# MySQL: show all available data when combining related tables even if the referencing foreign key is null

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT s.id AS id, s.grade_id as grade_id, g.name as grade_name, s.name AS name, s.scheduled_days as scheduled_days, s.period_id as period_id, p.name as period_name, s.start_time as start_time, s.end_time as end_time, s.teacher_id as teacher_id, u.name as teacher_name, s.classroom_id as classroom_id, c.name as classroom_name
FROM sections s, grades g, periods p, teachers t, users u, classrooms c
WHERE s.grade_id = g.id AND s.period_id = p.id AND s.classroom_id = c.id AND s.teacher_id = t.id AND t.user_id = u.id
```

Here it is possible for `teacher_id` and `classroom_id` foreign keys from *sections* table to be null. However mysql excludes entire columns from all related tables if any of those foreign keys are null.

How can I alter the query so that mysql will show data from *sections* table even if those keys are null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use outer joins.

First, you need to use modern JOIN syntax, available since 1992. With this syntax you can use `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, as in:

```
SELECT
  s.id AS id, s.grade_id as grade_id, g.name as grade_name, s.name AS name, 
  s.scheduled_days as scheduled_days, s.period_id as period_id,
  p.name as period_name, s.start_time as start_time, 
  s.end_time as end_time, s.teacher_id as teacher_id, 
  u.name as teacher_name, s.classroom_id as classroom_id, 
  c.name as classroom_name
FROM sections s
JOIN grades g ON s.grade_id = g.id
JOIN periods p ON s.period_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN teachers t ON s.teacher_id = t.id -- allows nulls for s.teacher_id
LEFT JOIN users u ON t.user_id = u.id -- allows nulls on t.user_id
LEFT JOIN classrooms c ON s.classroom_id = c.id -- allows nulls for s.classroom_id
```

This way, you will use the `WHERE` clause to include only "filtering conditions", but not "join conditions" anymore. It'll be much simpler to read and to debug.

Comment: Thank you. However MySQL is still skipping columns when `teacher_id` is null because there is no referenced `user_id` found from teachers table to combine teachers table with users table.

Comment: Fixed. I didn't see that one. Good catch.